# DIfference between Navision DB and SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, navision

I am new to Navision application.Can you please explain the difference between Navision DB and Sql Server DB?

Answer (score 2):

That completely depends on how you have Navision installed. See the entry on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_NAV) to see what I mean. It can be installed with SQL Server, or their native database server (referred to as 'Classic'). A google search for [Classic Navision Database](http://www.google.com/search?q=classic%20navision%20database) should get you well along in your research.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use sql syntax for database queries, then you need to install the sql server database. The native database does not support sql.

Answer (score -2):

Navision uses MySQL standard database, not just SQL. You should be able to see it depending on the tier composition you have on your NAV installation.

Comment: NAV never used MySQL. It used originally a proprietary db engine and later SQL Server.